# Imagemagick produce different results from GPUImage

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, gpuimage, imagemagick-convert

I'm currently using [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) to change the color(RGB) channels of images to produce "filter like" effects. The values I use for GPUImage are the X,Y values of the points of the color curve tool in photoshop. So for example I might have these points:

> **Photoshop curve tool** *!please note that the image doesn't represent
>   the current data points*:[image: photoshop curve tool]
>
> `Red:
>       0,0
>       0.1176,0.0196
>       0.2275,0.098
>       0.3294,0.3333
>       0.4392,0.549
>       0.7451,0.8627
>       1,1
>   Green:
>       0,0
>       0.0784,0.0196
>       0.1961,0.2431
>       0.5176,0.5882
>       0.7451,0.8039
>       1,1
>   Blue:
>       0,0.2549
>       0.1569,0.3529
>       0.3333,0.451
>       0.8314,0.7255
>       1,0.8039`

GPUImage handles these points without problems, however since Imagemagick doesn't support direct input of these values I have to convert each channel points to the curve's expression like this:

`Red: -237.407*u^6 + 634.277*u^5 - 615.934*u^4 + 261.501*u^3 - 44.054*u^2 + 2.617*u
Green: -32.880*u^5 + 80.544*u^4 - 68.222*u^3 + 22.707*u^2 - 1.148*u
Blue: -0.382*u^4 + 0.744*u^3 - 0.498*u^2 + 0.686*u + 0.255`

**I am using the im_fx_curves.pl script found [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#curves) to convert the points to the expression.**

So my process would normally look like this:

`` convert test_image.png \
\( -channel Red -fx "`perl im_fx_curves.pl 0,0 0.1176,0.0196 0.2275,0.098 0.3294,0.3333 0.4392,0.549 0.7451,0.8627 1,1`" \) \
\( -channel Green -fx "`perl im_fx_curves.pl 0,0 0.0784,0.0196 0.1961,0.2431 0.5176,0.5882 0.7451,0.8039 1,1`" \) \
\( -channel Blue -fx "`perl im_fx_curves.pl 0,0.2549 0.1569,0.3529 0.3333,0.451 0.8314,0.7255 1,0.8039`" \) result.png ``

---

However the results are slightly different. And I'm confused on why this is happening. I would gladly take any tips on what I might be doing wrong!

[image: result comparision]

Comment: I checked the two scripts (Perl and shell) and they produce identical  coefficients in all three cases. I tried doing it in RGB and sRGB colorspaces and that didn't help. I tried using the High Dynamic Range version of IM and that didn't help with rounding errors... am all out of ideas for a bit :-)

Comment: That's about what I've tried also, but thank you for trying. The investigation continues..

Comment: I also inspected the statistics of all three channels and there is not one channel that is significantly different between IM and GPUImage, and the differences are sometimes that the mean is higher and sometimes that the mean is lower, so they are not all consistently skewed one way or another - I believe the GPU uses fixed point - maybe that is the difference?

Comment: I think you're right. GPUimage seem to make identical results to the photoshop curves tool. Unfortunately ImageMagick doesn't seem to be too happy with the same curve points.

Comment: Maybe @BradLarson (author of GPUImage) will find a moment to share his insights - he said hopefully :-)

Comment: _fingers crossed_. I also tried to do it with [RMagick](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick) which is just a wrapper between ImageMagick and Ruby. However that even produces another result from GPUimage and ImageMagick ( from bash terminal ).

[This](https://gist.github.com/carlblock/f4ad6407d0e305dac4d5) is the script i use. And result looks like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/435397/result.png).